# «Обтікач» чи «обтічник» корисного вантажу?

Tags: from-english, вибір-слова, значення-слів

Натрапив у вікі на таку статтю *[Обтікач корисного вантажу](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%83)*, в англовікі відповідна стаття називається *Payload fairing*. На [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=fairing&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) подається обтічник:

> **fairing 1.** надава́ння//‌надання́ обтічно́ї фо́рми **2.** обті́чник
>   ['fεərɪŋ, 'fεrɪŋ]

Перекладач Google погоджується з цим.

От, що каже [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81):

> **-ач (-яч)** — досить поширений суфікс, надто при дієслівних
>   коренях:
>
> а) на означення особи носія чинності при дієслівних коренях: *ткач,
>   копач, шукач, глядач, слухач, втікач, нагля́дач, пома́гач, споживач,
>   перекладач, відвідувач, підспі́вач, викла́дач, допи́сувач,* іноді й
>   на означення не людей: *деркач* (порівн.: **-ак, -ар**).
>
> б) на означення знаряддя чинності: *сікач, колода́ч, рогач, брязкач,
>   нали́гач, виби́вач, попи́хач, вити́рач, пови́вач, натя́гач, вими́кач,
>   попи́хач, також кип'яч*.
>
> в) близький значенням до **-ань**: *вирлач* (= вирлоокий),
>   *бородач, гривач, горлач, волохач, носач*.

Яка різниця між *обтічник* і *обтікач*? Яке слово треба використати тут?

Answer (score 3):

[Стаття на Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81) виглядає калькою зі [сторінки на r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), яка, у свою чергу, є оцифрованим варіантом [книги](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/zmist):
**О. Синявський, "Норми української літературної мови" (1941)**.
До Синявського можна ставитися по-різному, і це може вплинути на відповідь на запитання.

Там же, у Синявського, бачимо означення суфіксу `-ик`:

> `-ик`, `-ник`, `-альник`, `-івник`, `-ільник`, `-чик`, `-їк` — надзвичайно поширений наросток, надто ж у сполученні з `-н-`, `-аль-`, `-їв-`, `-ч-`, з різним значінням при різних пнях:
>
> а) на означення осіб і конкретних предметів **за певною ознакою** (при прикметникових і дієслівних пнях): *верхови́к, січови́к, годови́к, молоди́к, судови́к, борови́к (гриб), варе́ник, крише́ник, цеге́льник, поде́нник, башта́нник, сви́стик, пи́щик, обі́жник, ві́рник, безді́тник, вла́сник, годи́нник, грабі́жник, банду́рник...*,
>   а потім із прикметникових слів `-ник` перенесений і на інші пні: *лі́жник, візни́к, скарбни́к, робітни́к, моло́тник, гребі́нник, курни́к, голубни́к, погрібни́к, березни́к* (порівн. `-ак`)...,
>   .а від дієслів на `-ати` `-альник`: *подава́льник, кида́льник, прибира́льник*..., на `-увати` `-івник`, *вартівни́к, гордівни́к, рахівни́к, чарівни́к*...,
>   від тих же дієслів, що мають дієприкметник на `-ений` (див. § 89), `-ільник`: *волочі́льник, громаді́льник, городі́льник, щепі́льник, кладі́льник, золі́льник* (іноді й `-ильник`: *лічи́льник* тощо). **Порівн. іще `-ач`**, `-ець`, `-ар`, `-ак`, `-ій`.

Для того, щоб відповісти на запитання стосовно конкретного слова ***обтікач | обтічник***, нам варто замислитися над його значенням. Є два слушні варіанти:

- [*nomen attributivum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomen_attributivum#English) — іменник, що позначає предмет через його атрибут, ключову/характерну **властивість**;
- [*nomen instrumenti*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomen_instrumenti#English) — іменник, що позначає предмет через його **призначення**.

Різні словники по-різному оцінюють можливість використання суфіксів `-ач` та `-ик` у цих двох ролях:

- r2u, як бачимо у цитаті з запитання, пропонує, що `-ач` може використовуватися в обох ролях, причому пріоритет надається саме *nomen instrumenti*; а для `-ик` основною роллю вважається або особа (що нам не підходить), або переважно *nomen attributivum*;
- інші джерела, як-то [Vidpo](http://vidpo.net/jaki-znachennja-sufiksiv-imennikiv.html), пропонують більш рівноправне застосування:

  > Суфікс `-ач` утворює іменники зі значенням:
  >
  > - особи по переважному **ознакою** (силач, вусань, трубач);
  > - предмета, який **служить для виконання дії** (тягач, пугач).
  >
  > Суфікс `-ик` (`-ник`) утворює іменники, що позначають:
  >
  > - особа по властивості або ознакою, які визначають його ставлення до предмета, заняттю (*цілинників, хімік, очників*)
  > - предмет, **призначений** для чого-небудь (*чайник, приймач, гаманець*);  (тут чистий *nomen instrumenti*)
  > - предмет, позначає книгу або твір (задачник, довідник); (зауваження: тут *nomen instrumenti*)
  > - простір або територію, покриті чимось або містять щось (*ялинник, малинник*).

Предмет, яким обладнуються космічні апарати та вантажівки з метою покращення аеродинамічних характеристик (обтікання потоком повітря) має явні ознаки саме  ***nomen instrumenti***. Тому:

1. У більшості випадків можна користуватися обидвома варіантами ***обтікач | обтічник***, бо словники пропонують обидва варіанти;
2. Якщо вдатися до [nitpicking](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nitpicking), то я б використовував ***обтікач***.